# How to create a security stamp value for asp.net identity (IUserSecurityStampStore)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my MVC-5 application, I have to **create security stamp values manually**. The current implementation of the identity team seems to use a guid.

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")
```

Is it safe to create a new Guid myself to use as a new security stamp value or will this lead to problems in future implementations of asp.net identity?
Is there a method to let the identity framework create such a stamp-value for me so that my implementation is safe for future changes?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Out of the documentation of the identity implementation for the entity-framework, it seems that it can be any random value:

[IdentityUser.SecurityStamp Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser.securitystamp(v=vs.111).aspx)

A guid seems therefore fine and the following code should be reliable also with future versions of asp.net identity.

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")
```

Answer (score 16):

ASP.NET Identity `UserManager` provides method `UpdateSecurityStampAsync(string userId)`which will automatically update users security-stamp. So that next time `validateInterval` ends user will be automatically logged-out and forced to sign.in again.

```
UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I was looking for a future-proof way on how to create the stamp-value manually (not to set it). Luckily I found in the docs of the asp.identiy Entity-Framework -implementation the  note that any random value will do. Please see my answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can look here that identity also uses Guid to create new Security stamps so i think there is no problem for you to create your own. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserManager.cs#L787  Identity only provides two methods `UpdateSecurityStampAsync` and `GetSecurityStampAsync` so you will have to create your own string if you want to have control.

Comment: This does not work for new users since userId still does not exist. The workaround could be to save the user first, then set the security stamp which will cause the user to be saved again. I think it is better to manually create the GUID.

Comment: @jstuardo this was answered 5 years ago and was valid for user's use-case

Comment: @ShoaibShakeel I have already solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

a bit late to the party, but these seem to work just fine:

```
        await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
        await _userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(user);
        await _userManager.UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(user);
        await _userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, true);
```